# Calling a function from a JS file not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function

I'm using React to view my pages.
I came across this problem if I try to call a function from a .js file nothing happens.
Basically, I have a small program that has two columns. Each column has a `<p>` tag that contains Column 1 and Column 2. There is a button below that once you click on it, both `Columns` should switch.

`index.js`

```
import "../style.css";
//import "./java.js";

class index extends React.Component {
render() {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="columns" id="columnsToSwitch">
                <div className="column1" id="column1_id">
                    <p>Column1</p>
                </div>
                <div className="column2" id="column2_id">
                    <p>Column 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="switch" id="switch_id" onClick={this.switchColumns}>Switch</div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default index;
```

`java.js`

```
const switchCol = document.querySelectorAll("div.columns");

const el = document.getElementById("switch_id");
if(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", switchColumns, false);
}

switchCol.forEach(switches => switches.addEventListener('click', switchColumns));

function switchColumns(){
    const makeSwitch1 = document.getElementById('column1_id');
    document.getElementById('column2_id').appendChild(makeSwitch1);

    const makeSwitch2 = document.getElementById('column2_id');
    document.getElementById('column1_id').appendChild(makeSwitch2);
}
```

`Method 1:`
I tried to import the .js file that contains the function.
Nothing is happening after clicking "Switch".

`Method 2:`
Using onClick within a  tag.

```
<div className="switch" id="switch_id" onClick={this.switchColumns}>Switch</div>
```

I get a couple of errors,

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'switchColumns')`
`The above error occurred in the <index> component:`

Comment: This isn't how you should be writing your react code. When using React, it is very rare that you'll need to use DOM methods such as `.getElementById()`, `.appendChild()`, `.addEventListener()` etc. You should instead be using props and state to manage event listeners and what gets rendered to the screen (this would be covered in some fundamental react courses / docs, eg: [this](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) tutorial from react).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just recently started practicing React and JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On This line:

```
const switchCol = document.querySelectorAll(".switchCol");
```

There's no elements with the class of 'switchCol' so you're going to get an empty `NodeList` which causes the `forEach` loop to not execute so there are no click events on the columns themselves.

In the `forEach` block:

```
switchCol.forEach(switches => {
    switches.addEventListener("column1", switchColumns);
    switches.addEventListener("column2", switchColumns);
});
```

"column1" and "column2" are not valid event listeners, and there doesn't need to be two event listeners for one element. I think you mean to write the following:

```
switchCol.forEach(switch => switch.addEventListener('click', switchColumns))
```

Now onto your main switching column function:

```
function switchColumns(){
const makeSwitch1 = document.getElementById('column1');
document.getElementById('column2').appendChild(makeSwitch1);

const makeSwitch2 = document.getElementById('column2');
document.getElementById('column1').appendChild(makeSwitch2);
```

}

Variables `makeSwitch1` and `makeSwitch2` are going to be undefined as you do not have any elements with an id of `column1` and `column2` respectfully. Which  is causing your issue with the second fix you tried.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer.
I didn't realize I type `column1` and `column2` instead of `column1_id`. I made some changes to the code.  The error is gone, but somehow the function is not working.

Comment: Actually, I just used `div` by itself. The function is working now. Not how I expected it, but it is working. Thank you!